# Typo3 - Access Global TCA with typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a way to access Global tca in typoscript and extract content like images, titles or any other information from it?

Comment: Please be more detailed in what you want to achieve? In TCA is the information about the structure of a table and record, not the data.

Comment: My question is not clear. You're right. Sorry for that.
The product is assigned to a category (New) and I want to use that category to get the product image, title and link (from product manager extension) and include it in the navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch database records in frontend for e.g. navigation, you can use the DataProcessor functionality in TypoScript.

Documentation with examples: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html#databasequeryprocessor